# Get the value for a variable from file using tcl

Tags: file, tcl, ns2

```
set lambda 1

set lambdaR [open LamdaValue.tr r]
  set Reader [read $lambdaR]
  close $lambdaR

foreach {x} $Reader {
   set lambda $x
  }
set $lambda [expr {$lambda + 1.0}]
set LambdaW [open LamdaValue.tr w]
puts $LambdaW "$lambda"
```

I'm trying to use this snippet of code to read the value of lambda from a file, modify it, and then write it to the file again. I'm using ns-2 which deals with tcl execution files. 
But the value of lambda doesn't change...
Can you spot where's the error?

Comment: Change `set $lambda [expr {$lambda + 1.0}]` to `set lambda` without the `$`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's best to write a small procedure to read the file and return its contents, and another to write the value back out.

```
proc readfile {filename} {
    set f [open $filename]
    set data [read $f]
    close $f
    return $data
}
proc writefile {filename data} {
    set f [open $filename w]
    puts -nonewline $f $data
    close $f
}
```

Then you can simplify the rest of your code a lot:

```
set lambda 1
# The catch means we use the fallback if the file doesn't exist
catch {set lambda [readfile LamdaValue.tr]}

set lambda [expr {$lambda + 1.0}]

writefile LamdaValue.tr $lambda
```

The other problem you were having was that you were doing `set $lambda`. This creates a variable with a strange name. In Tcl, you need to distinguish between *reading* the variable, when you use `$`, and *naming* variable (so a command can update it), when you don't use `$`. Unless you're wanting to keep the name of one variable in another variable, but it's best to only use that with `upvar` really to reduce confusion, or to switch to using array elements.

Comment: You are right it worked. Thanks. But I want to ask does that have to do with closing the file after each write and read?

Comment: Would you want `read -nonewline $f` or `read $f [file size $filename]` ?

Comment: @ShaikhaTheGreen It reads the whole file in and writes it out in one go too. It's the simplest thing that might work. You can do other approaches too; this is an area where there a _lot_ of options.

Comment: @glennjackman I don't know whether `read -nonewline` is suitable, but using `read` with a length is not really necessary now; the buffer management is now efficient enough that it is no big deal to just the single-argument form.